# Flask-Admin: change gregorian date value before submit

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a WTF form where I can enter a date. My date is in Persian calendar. When I submit the form it shows a field validation error and stop submitting.

I would like a hook or a function override before validation to change the date to Gregorian calendar. How can I do that?

I found `validate_form` but how can I access fields and change them?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to introduce my own datefield for processing form data. It converts date before storing in database and also after retrieving it from database.

```
class MyDateField(fields.DateField):
    widget = MyDatePickerWidget()
    def _value(self):
        if self.raw_data:
            return ' '.join(self.raw_data)
        else:
            # jalali is Persian clender
            return self.data and jalali(self.data, self.format) or ''
            # return self.data and self.data.strftime(self.format) or ''

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            date_str = ' '.join(valuelist)
            try:
                self.data = gregorian(date_str)
                #self.data = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, self.format)
            except ValueError:
                self.data = None
                raise ValueError(self.gettext('Not a valid datetime value'))
```